# SQL check against 2 columns

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-server-2016

I have a database with 1,362 different items, which can be stored in any one of 112 different warehouses.

I'd like to write something that would return the names of each item which has a stock value of 0 in all of the different warehouses.

I have the following already:

```
SELECT OITW.[ItemCode] AS [Item Code], INV1.[Dscription] AS [Description],
       OITW.[WhsCode] AS [Warehouse], SUM(OITW.[OnHand]) AS [On Hand]
FROM OITW
  INNER JOIN INV1 ON INV1.[ItemCode] = OITW.[ItemCode] 
WHERE INV1.[Dscription] LIKE 'BA SQUID ASSASSIN -Case%'
GROUP BY OITW.[ItemCode], INV1.[Dscription], OITW.[WhsCode]
ORDER BY [Warehouse], [On Hand]
```

Which returns:

[image]

This item would not be applicable because it has stock in 2 warehouses, for example.

I hope this question makes sense. Let me know if not and I will try to clarify.

Comment: Some sample data would be very useful in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the stock value is never negative, you can do:

```
SELECT INV1.[ItemCode] AS [Item Code], INV1.[Description] AS [Description],
FROM OITW INNER JOIN
     INV1
     ON INV1.[ItemCode] = OITW.[ItemCode] 
WHERE INV1.[Description] LIKE 'BA SQUID ASSASSIN -Case%'
GROUP BY OITW.[ItemCode], INV1.[Description], 
HAVING MAX([ON HAND]) = 0;
```

The changes from your query:

- The `GROUP BY` includes only the item and description, not the warehouse and on-hand amounts.
- The `SELECT` is modified to match the `GROUP BY`.
- The `HAVING` clause enforces your condition.
- I would advise you not to have spaces in your table names.  Use simple names so escaping the column names is not necessary.

Comment: I took your advice and then removed the WHERE clause which gave me exactly the result I wanted. Thank you very much,